# C# FubarDevelopment FtpServer. Как ограничить доступ (только для чтения) анонимным пользователям

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftp-сервер

Использую библиотеку FubaDev.FtpServer.
Я создал FTP-сервер с возможностью войти с логином и паролем и также с возможностью войти анонимно. Мне надо чтобы те пользователи, которые зашли анонимно имели доступ только для чтения.
Мой код :

```
using FubarDev.FtpServer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using FubarDev.FtpServer.FileSystem.DotNet;
using FubarDev.FtpServer.AccountManagement;

namespace FTPServer
{
    public class Program
    {

        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            services.Configure<DotNetFileSystemOptions>(opt =>
            {
                opt.RootPath = "D:";
            });


            services.AddFtpServer(builder => builder
                .UseDotNetFileSystem()
                .EnableAnonymousAuthentication());
            
            services.Configure<FtpServerOptions>(opt => opt.ServerAddress = "*");
            services.AddSingleton<IMembershipProvider, CustomMembershipProvider>();
            
            using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
            {
                var ftpServerHost = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFtpServerHost>();
                
                ftpServerHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None).Wait();

                Console.WriteLine("Нажмите ENTER чтобы остановить FTP-Сервер");
                Console.ReadLine();

                ftpServerHost.StopAsync(CancellationToken.None).Wait();
            }

            return 0;
        }

    }

}
```